# XSLT for BizTalk mapping and changing node name

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I need to map 2 fields from a large schema to a small schema (below), to produce a message to be sent to make a web service call.

```
<xs:element name="ds">
     <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
             <xs:element name="d1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

The same web method is used to update many different items, so contains 2 parameters: ID and another general update field which will take the text value of the update.

The ID parameter is always called ID, but depending on the type of item I have to update, the second parameter will change it's name.

So, in the BizTalk map (which I'm guessing should be XSLT):
The first field mapped across is an ID field, going from TargetID in source to ID in destination.  This is a direct mapping.
The second field will always be mapped to a field called 'd1'.
Based on an xsl:if, the node name of d1 will change.
eg:

if changeType in large schema = 'forename', d1 will become d_forename

if changeType in large schema = 'surname', d1 will become d_surname and so on.

There are going to be around 20 possible changeTypes, so I guess my question is, if I use an xsl:choose to evaluate the changeType (which will give me my ID and update value) how can I at the same time return the new name for the `<d1>` node?  I know it will be a called template but unsure where to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is presumable the possibilities around element naming.

What happens most of the time is the following:

```
<d_someOtherNode>
  <xsl:value-of select="/root/someOtherNode/text()" />
</d_someOtherNode>
```

However, what you can also do is:

```
<xs:element name="{concat('d_', name(/root/someOtherNode))}">
      <xsl:value-of select="/root/someOtherNode/text()" />
</xs:element>
```

The latter allows you to name the element as you please, in this case, concatenating the `d_` and name of the element you need (`someOtherNode` ).

Put this in the "if" structure or choose/when structure as you please, depending on your solution.

Comment: When I try this, I get "The '(' character, hexadecimal value 0x28, cannot be included in a name." What am I doing wrong? 

I had used the prefix "xs" as you have above but got an error that this was unknown, so changed it to "xsl".

Comment: @SimonRudd, can you add this in a separate question please?

Comment: OK, my logic was flawed, I fixed the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: This might actuallly be of value to you to: http://www.codit.eu/blog/2013/04/10/attribute-value-templates-in-xslt-an-example/